# ASP.Net - Can I Access My BasePage Properties From Within Markup?

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance

I want to be able to extend the System.Web.UI.Page class and then easily access those properties from the Markup.  I know I can do it from the codebehind, but is it possible from the Markup?  Take the following class.

```
public class MyBasePage : System.Web.UI.Page {
  public bool DoesThisWork { get; set; }
}
```

Then I want to be able to access it from the html markup, perhaps in the @Page directive.

```
<%@Page Language="C#" DoesThisWork="False" ...  %>
```

Of course the above Page is using the MyBasePage class instead of System.Web.UI.Page.

Comment: I don't think any of the answers are good enough for the question.  He is specifically asking about using it in the page directive which no answer addresses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the question is focused on how to use custom properties in the page directive - and the answer depends on whether you're using a **Web Application** project or **Web Site**.

For a **Web Site**, you need to assign **CodeFileBaseClass** to a non-partial class (under **App_Code** or in an external assembly). For **Web Application**, setting the Inherits directive should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can access the base page's properties from markup, just as you can any other property on the page.

For example:

```
<a href="<%=MyBasePageProperty %>">this is a link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly from the HTML, as in your example, but you can do this:

```
<td>Result: <%=DoesThisWork.ToString()%></td>
```